# Howto solve this typical Producer Consumer scenario

Tags: java, synchronization, integration-testing, testng

I encountered an interresting and I think very common synchronization problem in my test code.

This is the test (its a functional test that connects from the outside to the system), i run it via TestNG.

```
@Test
public void operationalClientConnected_sendGetUserSessionRequest_clientShallReceiveGetUserSessionResponse() {
    // GIVEN
    OperationalClientSimulator client = operationalClientHasEstablishedWebSocketConnection("ClientXY");

    // WHEN
    GetUserSessionRequest request = PojoRequestBuilder.newRequest(GetUserSessionRequest.class).build();
    client.sendRequest(request);

    // THEN
    assertThatClientReceivesResponse(client, GetUserSessionResponse.class, request.getCorrelationId(), request.getRequestId());
}
```

Basically i send a single request and wait for the correct response, this is what i want to verify in this test.

Behind the `assertThatClientReceivesResponse` there is a hamcrest matcher that looks like this:

```
@Override
protected boolean matchesSafely(final OperationalClientSimulator client) {
    Object awaitedMessage = client.awaitMessage(
            new Verification<Object>() {
                @Override
                public VerificationResult verify(final Object actual) {
                    VerificationResult result = new VerificationResult();

                    if (!_expectedResponseClass.isInstance(actual)) {
                        result.addMismatch("not of expected type", actual, _expectedResponseClass.getSimpleName());
                    }

                    // check more details of message ..   

                    return result;
                }
            }, _expectedTimeout);

    boolean matches = awaitedMessage != null;
    if (matches) {
        _messageCaptor.setActualMessage((T) awaitedMessage);
    }

    return matches;
}
```

Now to the interresting part, the synchronization in the `OperationalClientSimulator` class.
Two methods are of interrest:

1. awaitMessage which blocks until either a message that matches the given Verification is received or the timeout expired
2. onMessage received method which is called for each message that is received (over a websocket connection)

Basically what I want to achive is having the test thread block on the `awaitMessage` method until either the correct message is received (via `onMessage`) or the specified timeout elapsed.

```
public Object awaitMessage(final Verification<Object> verification, final long timeoutMillis) {
    // howto sync?
    return awaitedMessage; // or null
}

@Override
public void onMessage(final String message) {
    LOG.info("#Client {} <== received a message on websocket - {}", name, message);
    // howto sync?
}
```

About the test:

- The test thread will almost always be faster and therefor has to wait until the response is received via the `awaitMessage` method
- There can be very rare cases when the expected message is received before the test thread is checking for it (this basically means i have to save every received message)
- In this specific test case there are only a handfull of messages that are received (some heartbeat messages, the actual response and a notification), but in other cases there can be hundreds of messages which in need to inspect to find the expected message(s)

I was thinking about different solutions for synchronizing here:

1. The simplest of course would be the sync with the synchronized keyword but I think there are neater ways to do this
2. The onMessage received method could simply write into a blocking queue and the test thread can consume from it but here I dont know how to measure the timeout.. can I use a CountdownLatch?
3. Maybe I can do a non blocking solution where the producer (onMessage) writes into an Array and the consumer reads until it reaches an index that is published by the producer (like the LMAX Disruptor)

I know this is test code and performance is not really an issue here, I am just thinking how to solve this in a "nice" way.. you know.. because its christmas :-)

**So the actual question here is**, how do i "safely" wait for the message which i expect in my test with a timeout? Safely here means that i never miss a message or lose a message because of concurrency issues and that I also need to check if the expected message was already received.

How should I synchronize between the test runner thread and the thread that calls the `onMessage` method in the `OperationalClientSimulator` when a message is received on the websocket connection.

Comment: What do you want to test? (Also: 50-5k messages does not sound like a functional test at all,...)

Comment: Ok sorry, I think I did not formulate my question good enough. I edited the question. So basically its not about how i want to test my system its about how to write the test code/infrastructure.
What I am asking is how should i do the synchronization between the test runner thread and the thread that calls the onMessage method when a message is received on the websocket connection.

Comment: I actually asked, what the purpose of your test would be :P but anyway, I got it. The problem is, that websockets work asynchronously (as non-native english speaker, I am proud, I wrote this word correctly on my first attempt). You send a "GiveMeXRequest"-Request, and you cannot be sure, that you will receive "GiveMeXResponse". Interesting. Actually, I'm still not 100%sure, what some code snippets do. The "awaitMessage" and "onMessage", in what class are they and where do they come from? I assume, onMessage will be called by the WS-Client? The awaitMessage is a "testing-helper-method"?

Comment: Yes you are right, OperationalClientSimulator.onMessage is called by the WS Client and MyHamcrestMatcher.awaitMessage is called in the test thread.  The first method resides in a class that simulates a client of the system called OperationalClientSimulator and the second resides in an hamcrest matcher of the test framework that i am building.

Comment: Okay, my first thoughts for a solution were: @Test has a attribute timeout, so the awaitMessage-method would not be used anymore. The onMessage would delegate the call somehow to the test-method, which will only perform its assertions, if the expected Response is received. But this does not work, if the the expected Response was not received at all (where would you assert it? There's no order in JUnit).

Comment: Waaait a minute,... Another thought (even it does not look very elegant): test-Method sends Request. Then the test-method **waits** (e.g. using sleep()) The Client receives responses, for every response, it will give it to the TestCase, if the expected object is received, it will be assigned (maybe as member var), after the sleep, you do your assertions... would this work?